# Comparing the effects of independent variables on the dependent variable in a general linear model

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I have generated a glm between the dependent variable "cell regeneration" (continuous), and the independent variable "treatment option" (factor). This generated the result with a significant positive association between cell regeneration and treatment options 4 and 5. How would I compare these two associations? I have attempted to use the `contrast()` function, however, I do not understand the output of what I have generated:

```
library("contrast")
Contrast <- contrast(model1, a=list(ftreatment=c("4","5")))

glm model parameter contrast

 Contrast      S.E.    Lower    Upper     t df Pr(>|t|)
 3.423333 0.1006776 3.222016 3.624651 34.00 61        0
 3.710000 0.1318179 3.446414 3.973586 28.14 61        0
```

Comment: That is displaying the differences between each of those groups from the baseline category. R uses treatment contrasts by default. You should be seeking statistical help. I've seen non-statisticains attempt to approach this (and even claim it is valid to national professional audiences) by examining whether confidence interval overlap. Run away from anyone who tries to sell you on that approach.

Answer (score 1):

If your treatment vector is a factor - you probably did ANOVA.

Instead of glm I would use aov() in this case.

```
model1 <- aov(regeneration ~ ftreatment, data=yourData)
summary(model1)
```

To check how the treatments compare to each other some kind of post-hoc test should be used. R has [TuckeyHSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test) implemented for that. You can visually inspect the differences between the means of each cell type with a simple plot:

```
plot(TukeyHSD(aov(regeneration ~ ftreatment, data=youtData)))
```